# data that push back to 2D vector

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, list-initialization, braced-init-list

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> output; // 2D int vector


//normally, we can do
vector<int> v = { 44, 55 };
output.push_back(v);

//I found some example that we can do
output.push_back({ 22, 33 });
```

I know {} can be used to init an array or vector.
How the compiler know { 22, 33 } is an `vector<int>` rather than int array if i want to skip the line like `vector<int> v = { 44, 55 };` ?

and {22,33} is it a temporary object? (I know the return-by-value functions always give rise to temporary objects. )

Answer (score 2):

`{ 22, 33 }` is a braced-init-list, how it gets used depends on context.

In `output.push_back({ 22, 33 });`, `push_back` expects `vector<int>`, which could be constructed ([list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) since C++11) from braced-init-list `{ 22, 33 }` (via `vector`'s constructor taking `std::initializer_list`), then a temporary `vector<int>` is constructed and passed to `push_back`.